# How to check record isn't containing specific string?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+-------------------------------------------+
| id |                 col                       |
+----+-------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Peter|423421 , Alex Jon|61333             |
| 2  | Barmar|624321                             |
| 3  | Jack|624321 , Ali|312331 , Leonard|624321 |
+----+-------------------------------------------+
```

I need to check second row if isn't containing `824326`, then add this value `, Sara|824326` in the end of that. Something like this:

```
| 2  | Barmar|624321 , Sara|824326               |
```

---

Now I want to know, how can I check that field isn't containing thins number `824326` ?

Here is my try, I just need to the condition (to check existing)

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    col = CASE WHEN col = {:val doesn't exist} // <= How to write this condition?
                   THEN CONCAT(col,':newval')
                   ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "It is duplicate";
             END,
WHERE id = 2;
```

**Note1:** `:newval` is this `, Sara|824326` in the above query.

**Note2:** `:val` is this `824326` in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr). Try this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    col = CASE WHEN col INSTR(col, ':val') = 0
                   THEN CONCAT(col,':newval')
                   ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "It is duplicate";
             END,
WHERE id = 2;
```